# Group/Filter in phpunit doesnt execute specific test case

Tags: phpunit, selenium-rc

i have a suite that calls multiple suites and many functions for LOG,REPORT and Execution if i m trying the same 'Group or Filter' pattern its executes all the test cases without executing the selected single test cases.

**Edit:** I am using an array suite as follows,

```
$suite->addTestSuite('adminSuite');
$suite->addTestSuite('staffSuite');
$suite->addTestSuite('merchantSuite');

// Run the test
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run($suite, array(
            'junitLogfile' => $path_log
        ));
```

I am calling this file through ant.

Comment: form your question i understood that you have a file which calls the all suites which have testcases. and your annotations are in that test cases not in the file you are calling.

Comment: Yes! and due to multiple functions in my file it executes all the test cases, if i am executing single test case then Group/Filter are working

Comment: Give an example or two how you invoke PHPUnit.

Comment: Show some code! For example, how are you "calling all suites which have testcases"? When I'm trying to solve a problem like this, I create a new set of test cases that are as simple as possible, removing things until I find the most basic setup that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've added, it does exactly what you ask for. As you're running the tests with coded configuration, you would need to take care for filtering or selecting groups on your own as well. The regex based filter for test names is set with the `run` method as a parameter (in the parameter array). Interesting parameters for you might be: `filter`, `groups` and `excludeGroups`. Example:

```
// Run the test
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner::run($suite, array(
            'junitLogfile' => $path_log,
            'filter' => $yourFilter,
        ));
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could create simple test suite classes instead of a script that builds and runs a test suite. You'd pass the name of the test suite class to `phpunit` along with the filter and other parameters so you don't have to pass them to the runner yourself.